# Grunt : argument with colon

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to pass an url to a grunt task. Unfortunately the separator used by grunt is the colon which is also present in an url.

So how could I pass a url as argument to a grunt task ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went for the `grunt.option('optionName')` way.

from the command line it's called like following :

```
grunt myTask --optionName=httpmyUrl
```